# Linq to Entities performance difference between Expression/Func

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework

I was just testing a simple query that i'm accessing in different ways, but the speed of each can vary by up to 2 seconds. I was hoping someone can clarify why this is the case. My project is in it's very early stages, so I thought I'd make sure I'm doing it right before it gets too big.

Admittedly, my testing style isn't perfect, but i think it's good enough for this.

I'm using a generic Repository and UnitofWork, and I hit the DB (sqlexpress on my local machine) 10,000 times in this `while` statement. The table only has 64 records. Tests are run in Release mode.

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    using (var u = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        TestA(u);
        TestB(u);
    }
}
```

TestA (Func):

```
public void TestA(UnitOfWork u)
{
    Stopwatch s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    s.Start();
    var x = 0;
    var repo = u.Repository<MyEntity>();
    var code = "ABCD".First().ToString();
    while (x < 10000)
    {
        var testCase = repo.Single(w => w.Code == code && w.CodeOrder == 0).Name;
        x++;
    }
    s.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("TESTA: " + s.Elapsed);
}
```

TestB (Expression):

```
public void TestB(UnitOfWork u)
{
    Stopwatch s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    s.Start();
    var x = 0;
    var repo = u.Repository<MyEntity>();
    var code = "ABCD".First().ToString();
    while (x < 10000)
    {
        var testCase = repo.First(w => w.Code == code && w.CodeOrder == 0).Name;
        x++;
    }
    s.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("TESTB: " + s.Elapsed);
}
```

Even though i'm using the calls `First()` and `Single()`, they're not the built-in LINQ calls. They're part of my repository.

`First()` expression (IQueryable)

```
public TEntity Single(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
{
    return dbSet.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

`Single()` func (IEnumerable)

```
public TEntity First(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    return dbSet.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Test Name: MyTestMethod
Test Outcome: Passed

Result StandardOutput:  

TESTA: 00:00:02.4798818
TESTB: 00:00:03.4212112
```

Comment: Clearly you've edited your code before you've posted it. Can you please post your actual test code? We can't comment on why you're getting different performance until we can validate that you've correctly measured the performance.

Comment: Also, some queries scale better than others. Just because one query is slower now it doesn't mean it will be comparatively slower when you have more records. It might be that your tests are also meaningless. You probably need to validate your tests and run them with the number of records that you expect in the production environment.

Comment: I've cut my question down to Expression vs Func because it makes it easier to answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity My test code is pretty much identical to this, except the entity/obj names.

Comment: Then you have some serious issues with your testing. (1) I can't see how you got your timings. (2) Your queries are in a specific order - the first one will always take longer than the rest. (3) Iterating over `x` 1,000 times is going to measure far more than your query execution. You need to post your actual test code. The current code makes it harder to answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity In my question, I've stated that i comment out testCases that i'm not testing. So if i'm testing the "First()", i'll comment out the "Single()" line, and run it in VS2013 Test Explorer and check output for the time. Like I said, it's a fairly basic test. I stumbled upon it as a 'lets see which way is faster', and I found it interesting that the Expression was much slower than if i used a Func.

Comment: Try changing your test code into a couple of functions that each test a different query and then return the number of milliseconds the test takes to perform. Call them `TestA` and `TestB`. Then run them both, throw away the results, and run them again ten times each, alternating between them, and aggregate the results for each. Then let us know the results. This should be performed in a single run - don't comment code and do separate runs.

Comment: @Enigmativity Updated my question. Ran the test quite a few times, and got similar results each time.

Comment: You shouldn't do separate runs. Have a look at the answer I posted and run your tests that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, but just trying to make sure that the test results are more reliable.

Try writing your tests like this:

```
public long TestA()
{
    using (var u = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        var s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var x = 0;
        var repo = u.Repository<MyEntity>();
        var code = "ABCD".First().ToString();
        while (x < 10000)
        {
            var testCase = repo.Single(w => w.Code == code && w.CodeOrder == 0).Name;
            x++;
        }
        s.Stop();
        return s.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

(Obviously `TestB` is just a minor variant.)

And then your test method becomes:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    var dummyA = TestA();
    var dummyB = TestB();

    var realA = 0L;
    var realB = 0L;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        realA += TestA();
        realB += TestB();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("TESTA: " + realA.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("TESTB: " + realA.ToString());
}
```

Now your results are likely to be more accurate. Let us know the timings now.

---

Now try changing your tests like this:

```
public int TestA()
{
    var gc0 = GC.CollectionCount(0);
    using (var u = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        var s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var x = 0;
        var repo = u.Repository<MyEntity>();
        var code = "ABCD".First().ToString();
        while (x < 10000)
        {
            var testCase = repo.Single(w => w.Code == code && w.CodeOrder == 0).Name;
            x++;
        }
        s.Stop();
    }
    return GC.CollectionCount(0) - gc0;
}
```

This should determine how many generation 0 garbage collections are being performed. That might indicate that the performance issues are with your tests and not with the SQL.

Comment: IEnumerable/Func: `TESTA: 16846` IQueryable/Expression: `TESTB: 32189`

Comment: @malik - Excellent. Now can you change the return value for the tests to return the difference between `GC.CollectionCount(0)` at the start of the test and at the end? Put that code outside of the `using` statement. I suspect that the `Expression` version of your code is creating a lot more garbage collection.

Comment: @malik - I've added the change suggested to my answer.

Comment: `TESTA: 291`; `TESTB: 923` - so a lot more gc with Expression.

Comment: But why would this be happening? As per my comment to Evandro's answer, even in LINQPAD, the Expression is slower than the IEnumerable.

Comment: @malik - This is my whole point about getting your timings right. Your tests weren't showing the time it took to execute and expression versus a predicate as such. Other factors, the garbage collection, for example, were getting in the way. Expressions are expression trees of objects an you're creating a lot of them, hence the garbage collections. You really can only run a performance test against your actual database, with real data, performing just the single query. Otherwise there are too many factors that skew your performance results.

Comment: So what you're saying is, that my tests are inadvertently designed so that expressions will be slower no matter what, because of all the objects it's creating in the loop?

Comment: Even if i do single queries and print their elapsedticks, the func is quicker. But on a very large table, the expression would be the clear choice for performance.

Comment: @malik - Yes, pretty much. There may be a genuine difference in performance, but the way the tests are constructed you can't really tell. So the effort in determining performance is meaningless until you have real-word data and a real-word query to measure.

Comment: @malik - At the moment the difference between running a single query is about 0.34 milliseconds and 0.25 milliseconds. There is so little difference that there is nothing to go on here. There is no clear choice at all. It is like saying that if a Qantas jet from London to Sydney arrived 1 minute before a British Airways jet then Qantas is a clear choice for speedy travel. There's effectively no difference at all.

Comment: Well i just tried this test on a large table with around 3000 entries, and the Expression is much, much faster. Makes sense now. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

[`First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable.first%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with `Expression<Func<...>>` parameter is an extension method on `IQueryable<T>` and is used by query providers, like LINQ to Entities. Expression tree you provide is transformed into proper SQL query, which is sent to DB and only necessary rows are returned back to your application.

[`First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535050%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with `Func<...>` parameter is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` and is used by LINQ to Objects, which mean all the records from database will be fetched into application memory, and then element will be search as in-memory query, which is implemented as linear search.

You should definitely use the one from `IQueryable<T>`, because it will be more efficient (as database is optimized to perform queries).

Comment: This is exactly what i thought, until i ran the same query as expression (iqueryable) and as func (ienumerable) and the ienumerable was faster. Hence this question

Comment: What's implied, but not explicit, in @MarcinJuraszek's answer is that queries on `IENumerable<T>` always runs locally and queries on `IQueriable<T>` usually run on the server - but that's provider dependent.

Answer (score 1):

I will list some tests you might wanna try to help you narrow the differences between the operations.

**Check the actual SQL code**

Turn on the debug log for the queries or check it on the SSE logs. It is important since the EF engine should optimize the statements, and you can see what is really beeing sent to the DB.

As you said, the `First` operation should be faster, since there are optimized SQL operators for that. The `Single` should be slower since it has to validate all the values, and would scale based on the amount of rows.

**Use the real SQL on the database for a reference test**

Once you have the real SQL you can also check the differences of time elapsed on the database directly. Implement the same C# test on the DB, a Sotred Procedure maybe, and see what happens.

**Try the built-in LINQ for comparison**

I dont know if you already did it for the test, but try to use the native LINQ for a comparison.

I made many tests here using LINQ and there were no differences between the two statements you presented, so it actually could be the Expressions. (I used the SS CE btw).

Also, just for the sake of saying it, remmember to create Indexes for columns involved in heavy operations ;)
EF 6.1 has this feature built-in now.

```
  [Index]
  public String MyProperty{ get; set; }
```

Let me know if it was helpful.

Comment: `Single` is most likely transformed into `TOP 2` with additional check, how many elements were returned (exception thrown when there are 2 records returned) performed at application side.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I've updated my question with the `First()` and `Single()` methods. Both use `FirstOrDefault(predicate)`

Comment: @Evandro I put this whole thing into LINQPAD. This is now confusing me even more, because tehre's still a 2 second difference between IQueryable and IEnumerable. The IQueryable is in fact using a `where` statement in the SQL, and the IEnumerable is pulling the whole table in the sql.........