# LINQ to Entities Any() and Contains() slow with small list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm using EF 6 to get products from a database. The product categories are mapped as a navigation property on products, and the data is from a ProductCategory pivot table. The categories work like a tree (ie. every category can have sub-categories), but only the most specific product-subcategory relationship is stored in the pivot table. For example, suppose there is category path like this:

Electronics > Audio > Amplifiers > Integrated Amps.

A product that is an integrated amplifier has a record in the pivot table with its product ID and the Integrated Amps category ID.

I need to filter by category, but the product should show up even if filtering by a parent category, e.g. an integrated amplifier should show up in a list of Amplifiers. So first I make a List of the relevant category IDs. (This involves a separate query to the categories table, but it doesn't take long.) If the category filter is Amplifiers, the list is the ID of Amplifiers and the ID of Integrated Amps.

The problem is that the products query takes 10-20 times longer when I include the filter:

```
List<int> currentCategoryIdAndChildren = BuildCategoryIdList(currentCategoryId);

using (var db = new myContext())
{
    var products = db.Products
        .Select(p => new Product_PL
        {
            id = p.ID,
            name = p.Name,
            description = p.Description,
            categories = p.Categories
                        .Select(c => new Category_PL
                        {
                            categoryid = c.ID,
                        }),
        });

    // Filter by category
    products = products.Where(pl => pl.categories.Any(c => currentCategoryIdAndChildren.Contains(c.categoryid)));

    // Other filters, sorting, and paging here

    rptProducts.DataSource = products.ToList(); // Database call is made here
    rptProducts.DataBind();
}
```

I would expect that combination of Any() and Contains() to slow down quickly with large numbers of records, but I'm working with 22 items in products, 1-3 items in pl.categories, and 1-5 items in currentCategoryIdAndChildren. I'm surprised that with so few records it's slower by an order of magnitude. At this rate I'm better off filtering it client side, even though it means bringing back a lot of unnecessary records.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there another approach?

**UPDATE**: Express Profiler reports that the database query itself only takes 3ms, so I am guessing the performance has something to do with how Entity Framework works. Certainly it is slowest the very first time the LINQ is run (I know it needs to compile the query), but it's still relatively slow on subsequent calls.

Comment: you should filter at the same time as the select. when you call "products.Where" on the second line, it first has to enumerate Products. Move your Where clause to the end of your first linq call

Comment: @DLeh Are you sure that is correct? The first projection is not actually realised, so I'd expect the SQL code generation to be smart enough. One way to check would be to log the generated SQL.

Comment: I am not positive, but this is the first thing that I would try.

Comment: @Dleh The products don't get enumerated until they're actually accessed (such as with .ToList() or foreach). I've verified that the SQL call does not get made until then. I actually have several other conditional filters as well as paging after the code above, and it results in one giant filtered SQL call at the end. But I'll try moving the Where just for kicks.

Comment: How long the whole operation takes (not just the SQL query)? Any difference if you just call ToList without assigning it as DataSource?

Comment: @MysteriousWhisper I made a question about this recently. And I had the same issue: query = slow on small tables, but faster on larger tables. A workaround is, you could have an IEnumerable option and an IQueryable option. Use IEnumerable for small tables, but use IQueryable for large tables. I personally just stuck with IQueryable for all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599664/linq-to-entities-performance-difference-between-expression-func

Comment: @malik I experimented with IEnumerable and IQueryable in various places/ways, but I couldn't get it to make a difference.

Comment: I've found that EF takes a long time to initialize, especially with code first (about 2 seconds). For a web application where each request is a new process this can be detrimental to performance. Also, I have hit huge performance losses before just because I split my query into multiple statements. Lastly, you can always do a raw SQL query if you are worried about performance. Dapper is an awesome library which doesn't get in your way and provides ORM capabilities.

Comment: @SoftwareFactor There was no difference if I just called ToList(). The whole operation was taking a few hundred milliseconds on localhost. (Not very slow in the grand scheme of things, but on the server with a couple hundred products, page load times were going above that 1000ms threshold where they start to feel unresponsive.)

Comment: @Despertar Thanks for the input -- I'm not doing Code First, but I've been working with EF for its readability/maintainability. Once it's able to cache the query it takes <50ms. I'm satisfied with the performance now that I'm using PredicateBuilder, but I will look at Dapper -- it sounds useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried many different things and finally found a solution.

I believe the main slowdown happened when EF was translating the Contains() into a SQL query. The most noticeable thing, however, was that it did not appear to cache the query. From what I can gather, this is because the list of category IDs (currentCategoryIdAndChildren) was generated outside of EF, so it assumed it would be different every time.

I was able to speed things up by using the PredicateBuilder in LINQKit. This allowed me to create the logic more explicitly:

```
var IsInCategory = PredicateBuilder.False<Product_PL>();

foreach (int categoryID in currentCategoryIdAndChildren)
{ IsInCategory = IsInCategory.Or(pl => pl.categories.Any(c => categoryID == c.categoryid)); }

products = products.Where(IsInCategory);
```

This got me a bit better performance with my initial query, and MUCH better performance with subsequent queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try first filtering out the products and only then forming your models (Product_PL and Category_PL):

```
var filteredProducts = db.Products.Where(p => p.Categories.Any(c => currentCategoryIdAndChildren.Contains(c.ID)))
    .Select(p => new Product_PL
    {
        id = p.ID,
        name = p.Name,
        description = p.Description,
        categories = p.Categories
                    .Select(c => new Category_PL
                    {
                        categoryid = c.ID,
                    }),
    });
```

Comment: I get the same performance no matter where I put the Where, although the exact SQL is slightly different. I've updated my question to clarify when the database call gets made.