# Curious about slow performance when testing if a value is in a list in LINQ query

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

I have this piece of code (in VB.NET, but it should be applicable to any .NET language) that uses LINQ to retrieve some database records:

```
Dim validIDs = GetValidIDs() //this comes from server memory
Dim qry = From r in db.table
          Where validIDs.Contains(r.ID)
          Select r
Return qry.ToList()
```

This is many, many times slower than the following, both on my machine and on our test/prod servers:

```
Dim validIDs = GetValidIDs()
Dim qry = From r in db.table
          Select r
Dim ret = New List()
For Each r in qry
    If Not validIDs.Contains(r.ID) Then Continue For
    ret.Add(r)
Next
Return ret
```

The difference is doing the check for whether the record's ID is in a list of valid IDs on the database side vs. the .NET side after the records are pulled in.

Why is there such a significant performance difference here? I'm not necessarily looking for a fix, just interested in exactly what LINQ is doing here.

Comment: Can you provide some statistics? E.g. number of records in the table, number of Ids in the list, execution time etc.

Comment: Any difference if you use `validIDs.Any(x => x == r.ID)` instead of `Contains`?. Can you provide some details about `GetValidIDs()`? Like, is it returning an `IQueryable`, something else, ...

Comment: IvanStoev: records in table is <8k, the list can be up to that many. Execution time for #1 is ~20s, #2 is 2-3s very consistently. None of that should matter for this though, I'm curious about why there is a difference at all - the amount of difference is irrelevant.

grek40: GetValidIDs() returns an array of integers. Using Any() instead of Contains() produces a stack overflow exception, haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, looks like this question is a duplicate. I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24092704/885128

For those interested, since the list returned from GetValidIDs() was generated outside of LINQ, LINQ assumes that it could change, so it does not cache everything it could, leading to the slow performance.

If someone could mark this question as a duplicate of the one in the above link, that would be great. Thanks.